# How can a human terkow rogue use his special attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, attack

I'm running a published adventure that includes a male human terkow rogue as a monster. His melee attack stat is: 3 claws +17 (1d6+4/19-20 plus grab). His Special Attacks stats include blood drain and energy drain (2 levels, DC 19). However, no rules are provided in the adventure to indicate when the monster can use blood drain and energy drain.

Is the notion that I can make an energy drain attack using a melee attack, but instead of physical damage, I drain 2 levels from the PC? Am I supposed to assume that blood drain and energy drain just use a base attack bonus for their attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, special attacks are standard actions, with no limits on uses. As such, the normal rules for Energy and Blood Drain apply.

Blood Drain reads:

> The creature drains blood at the end of its turn if it grapples a foe, inflicting Constitution damage.

which means the creature must be grappled, and that Blood Drain is not a standard action. Energy Drain doesn't have a description for this, but reads:

> Location: Special Attacks and individual attacks

which would imply that you can use it like you would an attack move. The wording of [the source](http://paizo.com/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html) implies this to be true. Looking into [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/27224/8248), though, it seems like Energy Drain is played in whatever way makes the most sense. The special ability is a versatile one. In this case, it's your call. I'd probably stick to a grapple or touch attack.

If these conditions met for the attack, then the creature can use the special abilities as a standard action.

Primary source: [Universal Monster Rules](http://paizo.com/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html). Secondary source: My typical Pathfinder GM.

Comment: I looked up Pathfinder's Vampire monster and found this description for Energy Drain: A creature hit by a vampire's slam (or other natural weapon) gains two negative levels. This ability only triggers once per round, regardless of the number of attacks a vampire makes. As this monster only has claw attacks, I'd probably have the first one use the Energy Drain as part of its damage.

Comment: And for Blood Drain, a vampire must grapple and establish, or maintain, a pin for blood drain to occur, dealing 1d4 Constitution damage.

Comment: Makes sense. That's certainly one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A terkow is a variant Vampire.  The blood drain and energy drain abilities are unchanged and can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire), in the SRD.